# Why laravel can't use html facade

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

first Add in composer.json

> "illuminate/html": "5.*" and update composer

second

> add under 'providers'
>
> Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, add under 'aliases'
>
> 'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 'Html'      =>
>   Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

but after i run my page it say Class 'HTML' not found what the problem

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: i just install laravel lastest 5.2

Comment: "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*"
    },

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 . Basically, both form and html helpers were removed in Laravel 5. Alexey's answer is what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [Laravel Collective HTML & Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#installation) to make it work. Laravel developers removed this package from Laravel 5, so now you should install it manually.

Comment: why i see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31354079/6280656
 it mustn't install laravel collective

Comment: I've clicked it and it says you must. ) Actually, the answer has instruction of how to install it. `laravelcollective/html` package is Laravel Collective Html & Forms.

Comment: hey i just finish instrall collective but still same error

Comment: This happens. Try to run `composer dumpauto` and if it doesn't work, run `composer dumpauto -o`

Comment: Class 'HTML' not found

Comment: am try both but still Class 'HTML' not found

Comment: you want to see my app.php ??

Comment: I've had same problem few times. It was resolved by all cache clearing and running `composer dumpauto -o` couple of times. I know it's odd but that worked for me. Before that check if you have this class inside `vendor` directory.

Comment: Now the problem is with autoload files. It seems composer doesn't want to update them. Try to manually delete (you may backup them first) `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and `/composer.lock` and then run `composer dumpauto -o`

Comment: i try delete and run  composer dumpauto -o  but same error

Comment: example {!!Html::style('css/gogo.css')!!}

Comment: Oh, right. Well, now you know you need to use LC and what to do when you see `Class not found` errors. ) Glad it works now.

Comment: but in 5.0 i can use  {!!HTML::style('css/gogo.css')!!}

Comment: `HTML` and `Html` are just aliases, which you can change in `/config/app.php`. Maybe in 5.0 you've added it as `HTML`