# Class 'Html' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hope all of you fine with health and business.
I add these packages in my laravel composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "oprudkyi/laravel-mail-logger": "^1.0",
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"

},
```

and composer update

after that

Open config/app.php

add under 'providers'

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and the aliases

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

but still html not found..

```
{!! Html::style('newtheme/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
```

i tried other packages but composer said .. updated successfully .. but no one working. help me please

Answer (score 1):

I think this library purposely for Form and I could not find the HTML::style() example.

for calling the asset you can place in application's `public` folder and call using `asset()` function

```
<link href="{{ asset('newtheme/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

refer the helper function [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset)

If you still want to use `{!! Html::style('newtheme/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}` you need to change your package from `Collective` to `Illuminate` which has been removed in newest version of `Laravel`

Comment: asset method work. but when i change Collective to illuminate its not work.

Comment: need to update your composer and app.php as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350030/laravel-5-1-class-html-does-not-exist

Comment: yes Cod3rite.asset method working properly . but html still not working after change Collective to illuminate ....thanks for help..